# I can't open minecraft.jar on xfce4 on acer C720 chromebook

Tags: games, xfce, chromebook

I'm using xfce4 (Xubuntu) and I can't find the button for executing minecraft.jar as an application. I've tried using chmod, opening it with java7, and opening it with the terminal.

If I try to open it in the terminal (java -jar Minecraft.jar) I get:

```
unable to access the jarfile
```

even if I navigate to the downloads folder in the terminal.

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? What's "everything"? Unfortunately, your love for MC doesn't tell us what we need to know: how are you trying to open it; what happens when you do; do you have Java installed; are you using Ubuntu: what version? We need detail.

Comment: How did you attempt to open the jar file? Also, do you have java installed in your Chromebook Ubuntu environment? Overall, just specify in more detail the steps you took leading to this error.

Comment: details man, ill post an answer assuming you did nothing

Comment: sorry about the details, but i'm using xfce4 (xubuntu) and I can't find the button for exeucuting minecraft.jar as an application, i've tried using chmod, opening it with java7, and opening it with the terminal. If i try to open it in the terminal (java -jar Minecraft.jar) i get "unable to access the jarfile", even if I navigate to the downloads folder in the terminal.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How can I install Minecraft?](/q/5558/175814)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay, first you need to install java, run the following command

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre
```

Afterward you need to mark the file as executable, find the file and right click it, find the option marked "properties". A new window will pop up, at the top select permissions, then at the bottom checkmark "allow executing file as program". Then exit out of the window,and double click on the file (minecraft.jar).

If this answer helped you please mark it as accepted.

Comment: It won't let me get java 8, it says: unable to locate package openjdk-8-jre. and i'm using xfce4 (xubuntu), there is no button for marking it as executable.